# Using Jquery Animate to Move 2 items in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm trying to move two block at the same time within a container on hover and then off hover it will retain to its original state. When attempted this, it was unsuccessful. I was hoping for a little assistance doing this. here's an example of it:

```
var container   = $('#blockcontainer');
var container2  = $('#blockcontainer .block1');
var container3  = $('#blockcontainer .block2');
container.hover(function(){
   container3.animate({marginTop: '-100'}, 1000);
container2.animate({marginTop: '100'}, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gy9py/

Would truly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: are you trying to replace position of the blocks with animating effect?

Comment: Yes, I am. I used nanpx exampled and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I positioned the elements absolutely within the parent container.  The margin would always push the sibling element which is why it would disappear.  Also changed hover to mouseenter and mouseleave.

You could also achieve the effect with CSS3 transitions.

http://jsfiddle.net/gy9py/3/

```
<script>
container.on({
    'mouseenter': function(){
        container3.stop().animate({top: '0'}, 1000);
        container2.stop().animate({top: '100px'}, 1000);
    },
    'mouseleave': function(){
        container3.stop().animate({top: '100px'}, 1000);
        container2.stop().animate({top: '0'}, 1000);
    }
});
</script>
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.